# How to create a specific font family for use in an R package?

Tags: r, fonts, package, truetype

I need to ship a package with graphs and the client insists on using its own licensed font. The graphs have to be rendered as EPS and sent to the layout people for the reports.

I have the .ttf files for the font, with names like this :

- FontNameSans-Bold.ttf
- FontNameSans-Medium.ttf
- FontNameSerif-Bold.ttf
- FontNameSerif-Regular.ttf
- ...

I also have .eot, .svg and .woff versions of these files.

So I tried the `extrafont` package :

```
ttf_import('Path/To/ttfFiles')
fonts()
[1] "FontNameSans-Bold"     "FontNameSans-Light"   
[3] "FontNameSans-Medium"   "FontNameSans-Regular" 
[5] "FontNameSerif-Bold"    "FontNameSerif-Light"  
[7] "FontNameSerif-Medium"  "FontNameSerif-Regular"
```

I expected to see two families, but that obviously didn't work.

In the end, the ttf files should be included in a subfolder of the `inst` folder and I should have something like:

```
.onLoad({
  font_import(file.path(system.file(package = 'mypackage'),
                        "fontdir")
  )
  # something else to create a family FontName for 
  # use with postscript() or cairo_ps()
  loadfonts()
})
```

So I can then later do:

```
setEPS()
postscript('somefile.eps', family = 'FontName Sans')
plot(mydata)
dev.off()
embed_fonts('somefile.eps', outfile = 'somefile-embedded.eps')
```

**Question : What extra steps do I have to take in order to make the families available just like any other family?**

EDIT: I am aware that I have to load the fonts before I can use them. But I can't load the family if it's registered wrong. The question is about registering the font family correctly so the rest works as it should.

Comment: you need to use `extrafont::loadfonts` to actually load the fonts (import just puts them in in the font database). you specify which device in `loadfonts` as well (defaults to pdf). you can call `loadfonts` multiple times for multiple devices.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Obviously, but that is not the question. There's no point in loading the font when they're not registered correctly. Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is a bit late and probably you don't need it anymore. But this might be of interest for other users on the search.

Depending on your operating system you need to perform different steps. I have a package that includes several fonts in `inst/extdata/fonts/some-fonts.ttf`.

- On *Linux* systems one can copy those files when loading the pacakge to the *fonts* directory.
- On *Windows* one needs to copy the `.ttf` files manually to *C:/Windows/Fonts*.

To load the fonts when the package is loaded I adapted the `.onLoad` function:

```
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {
  if (Sys.info()[1] == "Linux") {
    dir.create('~/.fonts')
    file.copy("inst/extdata/fonts/some-fonts.ttf", "~/.fonts")
    system('fc-cache -f ~/.fonts')
  }
  if (Sys.info()[1] == "Windows") {
    windowsFonts()
    extrafont::font_import(pattern = "some-fonts", prompt = FALSE)
    extrafont::loadfonts(device = "win")
    windowsFonts()
  }
  print(extrafont::fonts())
}
```

- On *Linux* I only had to put the custom fonts in the *fonts* directory. Afterwards they were available to R.
- On *Windows* you need to *import* them using `extrafont::font_import` and to *register* them using `extrafont::loadfonts(device = "win")`.

Hope this helps you, others or my future self. ;-)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the solution. It doesn't work for me, however, if I try to load_all() my package I get  this cryptic error `error in nsenv[[f_name]](dirname(ns_path), package) :  unused argument (dirname(ns_path), package)`

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer @symbolrush. Do you have a suggestion for doing this for MacOS ((Sys.info()[1] == "Darwin")? Do I just copy the font files over as well? Thank you!!!